# Use last() in a FILTERXML function

Tags: excel, xpath

Let say i have the following XML in A1

```
<GlobalHistoricalQuote>
<Date>5/25/2017</Date>
<Quote>85.24</Quote>
</GlobalHistoricalQuote>
<GlobalHistoricalQuote>
<Date>5/26/2017</Date>
<Quote>84.31</Quote>
</GlobalHistoricalQuote>
<GlobalHistoricalQuote>
<Date>5/29/2017</Date>
<Quote>84.56</Quote>
</GlobalHistoricalQuote>
<GlobalHistoricalQuote>
<Date>5/30/2017</Date>
<Quote>84.24</Quote>
</GlobalHistoricalQuote>
```

I want to extract in Excel the last Date value;

If i enter this:

```
FILTERXML(A1,"//GlobalHistoricalQuote[4]/Date")
```

I get the correct value.

But if i enter that:

```
FILTERXML(A1,"//GlobalHistoricalQuote[last()]/Date")
```

I receive a #VALUE error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is correct locator:

> (//GlobalHistoricalQuote/Date)[last()]

to get the very last element use xpath below. You get all Date elements and picks last of found.

```
(locator)[last()]
```

to get each last element inside of another element use path below. You'll get last Date element (if there were more than 1, or the only present) in each `GlobalHistoricalQuote`

```
//GlobalHistoricalQuote/Date[last()]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but i tried that and still get the error

Comment: xpath by itself is correct to get the last element, be sure you didn't missed quotes/dashed `(//GlobalHistoricalQuote/Date)[last()]`. I'm not much familiar with FILTERXML function, but you can try this too: `(//GlobalHistoricalQuote/Date)[last()]/text()`

Comment: Unfortunately with no success. It's quite weird because if in place of [last()] i put [1] for example, it's working...it seem's like a problem in the FILTERXML function...